# NullPointer Exception while retrieving data from JSON

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to get data from my server using JSON and put the retrieved data to arrays
this is the fonction to retrieve *category,intitule,id_news,images*

```
public void getNewsFromServer(int beg){

    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("beg", Integer.toString(beg)));

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strURL);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    // conversion of the query into string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
     "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            id_news[i] = Integer.toString(json_data.getInt("id_news"));
            categorie[i] = json_data.getString("categorie");
            intitule[i] = json_data.getString("intitule");
            image[i] = json_data.getString("image");
        }


    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And this the **MainActivity.java**

```
String [] id_news= new String [20];
String [] categorie= new String [20];
String [] intitule= new String [20];
String [] image= new String [20];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...   
 try{
    //get data from the server and put it in tables
    getNewsFromServer(beg);
 }catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but i always get NULLPointerException
help please

these the logCat trace
[image: logCat]

this the initialisation of the context **Context context = this;**

but it generate another exceptions **NetworkOnMainThreadException** and **NullPointerException** and **JSONException:End of input at character 0**..

Comment: and the stacktrace is?

Comment: paste strack trace of exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixe the problem by using the AsynkTask

```
private class Asyn_GetNewsFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        getNewsFromServer(beg);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
                    //do what ever you want
    }
}
```

thx for your help

Answer (score 2):

The NPE comes from `Toast` initialization. Make sure the `context` you pass there is not null.

Since you use the toasts in exception catch blocks, log the exception stacktraces with e.g. `e.printStackTrace()` to get a hold on the root cause. (Prime suspect: `NetworkOnMainThreadException`)

For `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, do your network ops on a background thread. See [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) for more.

Comment: i make an update , check it please

Answer (score 0):

In your call to Toast, the `context` variable is most likely null.

**Never** catch a NullPointerException. Make sure it never gets thrown.

Answer (score 0):

As laalto points out the `NPE` is coming in `Toast` statement.

Can you give a code snippet of how you have initialized context.

Also try using `getActivity()` there once and see if it solves the issue.

If it does then `override onAttach()` and initialize your `context` inside it. As directly giving `getActivity()` is not a good practice.

`NetworkOnMainThreadException` is caused because you should make network calls on a separate thread.
use something like:

```
Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
           //your network calls here
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

thread.start();
```

Comment: did you try writing getactivity() instead of context in all of your Toast statements?

Comment: yes but still have the same problems, take a look of my edit please